# MySQL , How to Select by rand() and update colums in same query?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I need a way to select a row by rand() and update it at same query On MYSQL
I tried This Code But Did not any answer:

```
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
select * from articles where status = 3 and name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RAND() limit 0,1;
update articles set status = 4 ;
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for Me:

```
update articles set `status` = 4 where id in (
  SELECT id FROM  (
    select id from articles where status = 3 and name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RAND() limit 0,1
  ) tmp
);
```